# Why the PHP documentation indicates to not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() even with allowed_classes=false?

Tags: php, input, serialization, documentation

I understand the risks of `unserialize()` with untrusted user data with no `$options` or for example with `allowed_classes=true`. But **why** should untrusted user data **not** be given even if `allowed_classes=false` ??

If `allowed_classes=false` no objects should be instantiated and so there should be no chance of exploiting the API, at least not from that perspective.

Comment: As documentation said, it could trigger autoloading. The result may have filtered out any classes. But that is not the same. Also serializing is no good idea, because the data can be manipulated easily. That's why json or hmac is a good idea.

Comment: So PHP it's so fucked that even if you have a parameter to disable **all_classes** then still, some object could be "auto-loaded" ?
Wow 
Could you (@MarkusZeller) elaborate on "it could trigger autoloading. The result may have filtered out any classes" - are you saying it would load them and afterwards filter them?? 

using hmac does not seem like the best design choice as the key could leak or be guessed or who knows the server could "sign" anything if stupidly programmed, etc.

Comment: I don't know, but that gained my interest now and will do an experiment... But that was what I read from the documentation.

Comment: The `allowed_classes => false` won't trigger the autloader, but it creates some alias emtpy class. https://pastebin.com/Lfq88rE5 Maybe this could be a problem if multiple autoloaders are chained.

Comment: Because in order for `unserialize()` to work it must necessarily go outside certain guardrails in the PHP core and has been the source of _many_ high-scoring CVEs. There is simply no setting that is "safe enough" that unserializing anything that you yourself did not serialize and have 100% control of at all times is just an awful idea. If you just want the actual reasoning your best bet is to check the mailing list archives.